# Can not filter results in vimeo api GET call with fields param

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using Vimeo API, while making a get call to access a user's video I am doing

```
https://api.vimeo.com/users/61402929/videos?access_token=token
```

this is returning a json response

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 25,
    "paging": {
        "next": null,
        "previous": null,
        "first": "/users/61402929/videos?access_token=365879aad6244864dab70902890fc1a1&page=1",
        "last": "/users/61402929/videos?access_token=365879aad6244864dab70902890fc1a1&page=1"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "uri": "/videos/200383630",
            "name": "Bhuvan bam _ Bb ki vines _ playing piano _ Saagar jaisi aankhon waali  _ bhuvan bam  live (360p_30fps_H264-96kbit_AAC)",
            "description": "BB Ki Vines",
            "link": "https://vimeo.com/200383630",
            "duration": 59,
            "width": 320,
            "language": null,
            "height": 320,
            "embed": {
                "uri": null,
                "html": "<iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/200383630?badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0\" width=\"320\" height=\"320\" frameborder=\"0\" title=\"Bhuvan bam _ Bb ki vines _ playing piano _ Saagar jaisi aankhon waali  _ bhuvan bam  live (360p_30fps_H264-96kbit_AAC)\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>",
                "buttons": {
                    "like": true,
                    "watchlater": true,
                    "share": true,
                    "embed": true,
                    "hd": false,
                    "fullscreen": true,
                    "scaling": true
                },
                "logos": {
                    "vimeo": true,
                    "custom": {
                        "active": false,
                        "link": null,
                        "sticky": false
                    }
                },
                "title": {
                    "name": "user",
                    "owner": "user",
                    "portrait": "user"
                },
                "playbar": true,
                "volume": true,
                "color": "00adef"
            },
            "created_time": "2017-01-20T17:57:04+00:00",
            "modified_time": "2017-01-20T17:58:41+00:00",
            "release_time": "2017-01-20T17:57:04+00:00",
            "content_rating": [
                "unrated"
            ],
            "license": null,
            "privacy": {
                "view": "anybody",
                "embed": "public",
                "download": true,
                "add": true,
                "comments": "anybody"
            },
            "pictures": {
                "uri": "/videos/200383630/pictures/613872508",
                "active": true,
                "type": "custom",
                "sizes": [
                    {
                        "width": 100,
                        "height": 75,
                        "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/613872508_100x75.webp?r=pad",
                        "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F613872508_100x75.webp&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "width": 200,
                        "height": 150,
                        "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/613872508_200x150.webp?r=pad",
                        "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F613872508_200x150.webp&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "width": 295,
                        "height": 166,
                        "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/613872508_295x166.webp?r=pad",
                        "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F613872508_295x166.webp&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "width": 640,
                        "height": 640,
                        "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/613872508_640x640.webp?r=pad",
                        "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F613872508_640x640.webp&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "width": 960,
                        "height": 960,
                        "link": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/613872508_960x960.webp?r=pad",
                        "link_with_play_button": "https://i.vimeocdn.com/filter/overlay?src0=https%3A%2F%2Fi.vimeocdn.com%2Fvideo%2F613872508_960x960.webp&src1=http%3A%2F%2Ff.vimeocdn.com%2Fp%2Fimages%2Fcrawler_play.png"
                    }
                ],
                "resource_key": "fdb74e1e2dcaf7c929cfe14240765f45f2d2a302"
            },
            "tags": [],
            "stats": {
                "plays": 0
            },
            "metadata": {
                "connections": {
                    "comments": {
                        "uri": "/videos/200383630/comments",
                        "options": [
                            "GET",
                            "POST"
                        ],
                        "total": 0
                    },
                    "credits": {
                        "uri": "/videos/200383630/credits",
                        "options": [
                            "GET",
                            "POST"
                        ],
                        "total": 1
                    },
                    "likes": {
                        "uri": "/videos/200383630/likes",
                        "options": [
                            "GET"
                        ],
                        "total": 0
                    },
                    "pictures": {
                        "uri": "/videos/200383630/pictures",
                        "options": [
                            "GET",
                            "POST"
                        ],
                        "total": 1
                    },
                    "texttracks": {
                        "uri": "/videos/200383630/texttracks",
                        "options": [
                            "GET",
                            "POST"
                        ],
                        "total": 0
                    },
                    "related": null
                },
                "interactions": {
                    "watchlater": {
                        "added": false,
                        "added_time": null,
                        "uri": "/users/61402929/watchlater/200383630"
                    }
                }
            },
            "user": {
                "uri": "/users/61402929",
                "name": "Rishabh Kumar",
                "link": "https://vimeo.com/user61402929",
                "location": null,
                "bio": null,
                "created_time": "2017-01-11T16:15:43+00:00",
                "account": "basic",
                "pictures": null,
                "websites": [],
                "metadata": {
                    "connections": {
                        "activities": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/activities",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ]
                        },
                        "albums": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/albums",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "appearances": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/appearances",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "categories": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/categories",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "channels": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/channels",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "feed": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/feed",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ]
                        },
                        "followers": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/followers",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "following": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/following",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "groups": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/groups",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "likes": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/likes",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "moderated_channels": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/channels?filter=moderated",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "portfolios": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/portfolios",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "videos": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/videos",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 1
                        },
                        "watchlater": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/watchlater",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "shared": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/shared/videos",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "pictures": {
                            "uri": "/users/61402929/pictures",
                            "options": [
                                "GET",
                                "POST"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        },
                        "watched_videos": {
                            "uri": "/me/watched/videos",
                            "options": [
                                "GET"
                            ],
                            "total": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "preferences": {
                    "videos": {
                        "privacy": "anybody"
                    }
                },
                "content_filter": [
                    "language",
                    "drugs",
                    "violence",
                    "nudity",
                    "safe",
                    "unrated"
                ],
                "resource_key": "6fe192b4cb782d1341fbf3fb3d0ba04a0295236d"
            },
            "app": null,
            "status": "available",
            "resource_key": "cad1f2b7d388491329363a4936f0219fa4dfd18b",
            "embed_presets": null
        }
    ]
}
```

however I am only interested in fields paging, total, and some fields of data array therefore i am using filter as below

```
https://api.vimeo.com/users/61402929/videos?access_token=token&fields=paging,data.name,data.description,data.link,data.pictures.sizes.link
```

but the response of above call is

```
{
"total": 1,
"page": 1,
"per_page": 25,
"paging": {
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "first": "/users/61402929/videos?access_token=365879********0902890fc1a1&fields=paging%2Cdata.name%2Cdata.description%2Cdata.link%2Cdata.pictures.sizes.link&page=1",
    "last": "/users/61402929/videos?access_token=365879********0902890fc1a1&fields=paging%2Cdata.name%2Cdata.description%2Cdata.link%2Cdata.pictures.sizes.link&page=1"
},
"data": [
    []
]
```

}

Edit: Also the response for the call

```
https://api.vimeo.com/users/61402929/videos?access_token=token&fields=paging
```

is

```
{
"total": 1,
"page": 1,
"per_page": 25,
"paging": {
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "first": "/users/61402929/videos?access_token=365879*********70902890fc1a1&fields=paging&page=1",
    "last": "/users/61402929/videos?access_token=365879*********70902890fc1a1&fields=paging&page=1"
},
"data": [
    []
]
```

}

I am unable to figure out why the request is not being processed correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of things: First, the access token should be passed in the auth header of the request, not in the request uri as you mentioned: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#making-requests

With regards to the fields filter, the filter only applies to the keys nested under `data`. The `paging` array is always returned for requests where multiple items are returned.

So your example request should look like this:

```
https://api.vimeo.com/users/61402929/videos?fields=name,description,link,pictures.sizes.link
```

More info here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/spec#json-filter

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Using field instead of data.field solved the problem. However sending token in uri instead of header also seems to work. Are there any particular advantages of sending it through header?

Comment: Sending the token in the header is the officially supported method of providing the token. I think the old APIs used to support the token in the request uri, and when the new API launched it was supported as a legacy thing, but officially that method of authentication may break at any time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to this question, but in case anyone else like me ends up finding this page through search results, I have wasted a couple of hours of my life with a similar problem, wondering why the results returned by Vimeo's API were seemingly completely erratic, when dialing up the API using Laravel with [this package](https://github.com/vimeo/laravel) like so:

```
$response = Vimeo::request('/me/albums/xxxxxxx/videos?fields=name,uri,duration,width,height,link', `['per_page' => 100], 'GET');`
```

After a lot of trial and error I discovered that it always seemed to miss the last field listed in the query parameter.

Anyway, the solution was to always send the request with a trailing comma! i.e.

```
$response = Vimeo::request('/me/albums/xxxxxxx/videos?fields=name,uri,duration,width,height,link,', `['per_page' => 100], 'GET');`
```

Is this an absolutely face-palmingly ridiculous requirement? Why, yes. Yes it is. But there you have it.